# Disable Featured Image Link

Tags: wordpress-featured-image

I am an amateur in code development, but know enough to get around. I have been trying for days to disable the link associated with the featured image, so in fact, the image is static, and does not link to a post.

For information sake, I am using the Gridsby Theme.

Would love any advice.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you talking about? Wordpress?

Comment: Yes, Wordpress.